# Raspberry pi 2 B won't detect temp sensor DS18B20

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-2, temperature, ds18b20

I have a rasp pi 2 b+ and a temperature sensor DS18B20.

I can't get my `ls /sys/bus/w1/devices` command to show anything other than `w1_bus_master1`.

I suspect it is a problem with my set up but I've tried a number of combinations but still no results.

I'm using a 10kOhm resistor, a Vilros cobbler and just updated raspbian (4.1.19-v7+).

I've tried adding this to my /boot/config.txt `dtoverlay=w1-gpio`

Pics of setup:

The crocodile clips go to the three connections for the DS18B20

[image: The crocodile clips are connected to the DS18B20]
[[image]

Comment: I have no idea what the solution is

Comment: Have you a meter?  If so check the breadboard voltages.  Is 5V actually 5V and 3V3 actually 3V3?  A common error is to connect the ribbon cable the wrong way around.

Comment: I don't currently have one but is there another way to tell if it's the wrong way around? I'll set everything up and try flipping it

Comment: nope, nothing has changed

Comment: Do you have a DS18B20 or a DS18B20-P?

Comment: Waterproof DS18B20

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Edit your /boot/config.txt line to contain:

   ```
   dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4,pullup=on
   ```
2. sudo lsmod, check for w1_therm. If it's not loaded, edit /etc/modules to contain:

   ```
   wire
   w1-gpio
   w1-therm
   ```
3. Use a 4.7k resistor instead as recommended in datasheet. If you only have 10k ones, try to use 2 of them in parallel for a resulting impedance of 5kOhm, for testing purposes.

Reboot after each change. Good luck!

Comment: Sounds good. Will check when I'm home tonight but I remember that I currently already have dtoverlay, gpiopin and the lsmod has everything you suggested. Will try pullup and paralleling the resistors!

Comment: @darkace I used https://www.kompf.de/weather/pionewiremini.html for setting up my DS1820. It's in German but you should get the point. I also operate my DS1820 in parasite-powered mode so another idea could be to connect the yellow wire that leads to your DS1820 to GND. (edit: works fine in both modes)